# Webpack doesn't generate bundle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

my webpack doesn't generate file though no errors shown. PLS help :D
i'm new to all this so dont be harsh pls :D

code in webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry : ['./app/index.js'],
    output : {
        path : '/build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

using npm run build, no errors returned.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "es6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html

Comment: I did but like I said I am new to this and don't really understand it like all of you, that is why i posted question. I even read other question that may have answer in them but none of them have simple configuration as I do. Still cant find the answer. If u know it i would really appreciate it. Thx

Comment: How are you running webpack? Ah, it's just "webpack". You need to pass in the config, `webpack --config webpack.config.js` edit nevermind it should do that automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a fresh directory, copying in your code as is, I get the following:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/build'
    at Error (native)
```

It's trying to access the root level `/build` directory (which doesn't exist, at least for me).

Tweaking the config a bit more leads to this:

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    entry : ['./app/index.js'],
    output : {
        // Get the path including the current directory node is running in
        path : path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

Which spits out a successful bundle.

There were no errors? Any output at all?